# java path is not set when add path field in environment variables

Tags: java, path

I am new to java programming language. First i download the sdk and install it in to my pc.
Then i add a new environment variable like this

```
  path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin
```

After creating this i entered javac in my cmd prompt. But i didn't get any thing.

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
 operable program or batch file.
```

i am look in to some tutorials they said this way for setting path. if any one know about this please help me.

Comment: you need not create a new "Path " variable..add the location of JDK\bin to existing Path variable under System variables.. Restart cmd prompt and type javac (PS: ";" is the seperator used.

Comment: Once you set the path, your computer need to be restarted to reflect those changes.Did you do that ?

Comment: @RadhamaniMuthusamy - No.. Computer should not be restarted.. restart only the cmd prompt..

Comment: To set an environment variable in a command window you use the `set` command.  For example `set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin"`.  The quotes are important because of the space in the directory name `Program Files`.  However, as others have suggested, it's better to modify the system's `path` environment variable.

Comment: yes. i didn't restart the cmd prompt. After restart this working perfect. thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click My Computer -> Advance Options -> Environment Varibles -> Under User Variables
2. Click New
3. Under Variable name type **JAVA_HOME**
4. Under Variable value type **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk**  (without bin)
5. Click OK
6. Again Click New
7. Under Variable name type **PATH**
8. Under Variable value type **%JAVA_HOME%\bin**
9. Click OK

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Right click My Computer->Advence Option->Environment Varibles->SystemVariables 
2. variable : Path->Edit
3. Copy your jdk bin directory i.e. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin
4. Paste it after putting a semi-colon(;) in value section
```

To test it..Open cmd with administrator and type `java -version`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Step for Windows for Permanent Path setup:

```
    1) My Computer Properties

    2) Advanced Option

    3) Environment Variable

    4) New tab

    5) Name= Path

    6) Value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin 

    7) Ok
```

**EDIT**

See that you are into c:\Windows\System32 and your admin
        That's IT now type javac and its DONE

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your jdk is installed in  c:\Program Files\java\jdk directory

EDIT "Path" system variable 
which would be --> C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32

To --> 
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;c:\Program Files\java\jdk\bin